# remove some div or some html via jquery ? possible?

Tags: jquery

i can add some html via jquery on my main menu. how can i remove last items html via  jquery is that possible ?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".menubarinner ul li" ).after( "<div class='sperator'></div>" );
});
```

Comment: `$('.separator').remove()`?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+remove – was that too hard for you to do on your own …?

Comment: i have six li. so, i just remove latest ones sperator @Cbroe i really googled it. than i confused.

Comment: From someone who has – allegedly – searched already, i would expect a question a little more specific than _“is it possible”_ …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> remove latest ones sperator

So `$('.separator').last().remove();`

http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: thats what i want thanks for fast help @sdespont.

Answer (score 0):

You just find last li of ul and then remove that -

```
$('ul li:last-child').remove();
```